# How do I combine the values of a single order?

Tags: python, pandas

I cannot figure out how to combine rows with the same productcode together to sum their total order values (quantityordered * priceeach). For example:

```
orderdetails_df
Out[24]: 
      ordernumber productcode  quantityordered  priceeach  orderlinenumber
0           10100    S18_1749               30     171.70                3
1           10100    S18_2248               50      67.80                2
2           10100    S18_4409               22      86.51                4
3           10100    S24_3969               49      34.47                1
4           10101    S18_2325               25     151.28                4
           ...         ...              ...        ...              ...
2991        10425    S24_2300               49     112.46                9
2992        10425    S24_2840               31      33.24                5
2993        10425    S32_1268               41      86.68               11
2994        10425    S32_2509               11      43.83                6
2995        10425    S50_1392               18     105.33
```

I need to combine all ordernumbers 10100 and their corresponding price values (30 * 171.70, etc.) to get the total value of the entire order. Is there some code that will combine all like-wise ordernumbers and output their total values?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to compute order value and then using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), sum the order value for each order.

```
df['order_value'] = df['quantityordered'] * df['priceeach']
df.groupby('ordernumber')['order_value'].sum().reset_index(name='total_order_value')
```

Output

```
ordernumber total_order_value
0   10100   12133.25
1   10101   3782.00
2   10425   10576.99
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. You are my hero

Comment: Glad it worked. Feel free to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) my answer. Happy coding. @MatthewLynn

Answer (score 1):

Let us do these things separately:

1. first we create a column that calculates the price of the quantity; and
2. next we sum up the ordernumbers.

We can do that by:

```
df['pricequantity'] = df['priceeach'] * df['quantityordered']
```

then we can sum up the prices with:

```
df.groupby('ordernumber')['pricequantity'].sum()
```

For the given sample data (except the last line that was missing an `orderlinenumber`), we get:

```
>>> df.groupby('ordernumber')['pricequantity'].sum()
ordernumber
10100    12133.25
10101     3782.00
10425    10576.99
Name: pricequantity, dtype: float64
```